# React-draggable npm package prevents clicking inside input field

Tags: reactjs, draggable

I am using the npm package "[react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable)" to allow drag on an element that contains a form.

Now that I can drag around my element, I am very happy... But the input fields are not clickable as in you're not able to click and type. The only thing i can do is click and hold to then type.

Snippet:

```js
render() {
        return (
            <Draggable>
                <div className="pokedex">
                    <div className="screen">
                        {this.state.isSearching ? (<Loader/>) : null}
                        {this.state.hasFound ? this.renderResult() : null}
                        {this.state.hasError ? (<p className="text-center error">{this.state.hasError}</p>) : null}
                    </div>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>
                        <input className="field" type="text" placeholder="Who is this pokemon?" onChange={(e) => this.setPokemon(e.target.value)}/>
                        {this.state.isSearching ? <input className="button text-center" disabled type="submit" value="Find!"/> : <input className="button text-center" type="submit" value="Find!"/>}
                    </form>
                    <div className="button-group">
                        <div className="blue-button"/>
                        <div className="green-button"/>
                        <div className="orange-button"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Draggable>
        )
    }
```

Is there a way to avoid this kind of behaviour?

Comment: I would try adding `stopPropagation` to the `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` events on the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `event.stopPropagation()` onMouseDown did the trick!

> Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

Snippet:

```js
render() {
        return (
            <Draggable>
                <div className="pokedex">
                    <div className="screen">
                        {this.state.isSearching ? (<Loader/>) : null}
                        {this.state.hasFound ? this.renderResult() : null}
                        {this.state.hasError ? (<p className="text-center error">{this.state.hasError}</p>) : null}
                    </div>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>
                        <input onMouseDown={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}}  className="field" type="text" placeholder="Who is this pokemon?" onChange={(e) => this.setPokemon(e.target.value)}/>
                        {this.state.isSearching ? <input className="button text-center" disabled type="submit" value="Find!"/> : <input className="button text-center" type="submit" value="Find!"/>}
                    </form>
                    <div className="button-group">
                        <div className="blue-button"/>
                        <div className="green-button"/>
                        <div className="orange-button"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Draggable>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I had to code a little 'observer' to detect if the user was actually dragging or clicking. The principle is to compute the distance between the drag start point and the drag stop point:

```
function useClickObserver(callback)
{
    const [dragStartPos, setDragStartPos] = React.useState(new Point())
    const onStart = (_, data) =>
    {
        setDragStartPos(new Point(data.x, data.y))
    }
    const onStop = (_, data) =>
    {
        const dragStopPoint = new Point(data.x, data.y)
        if(Point.dist(dragStartPos, dragStopPoint) < 5)
        {
            callback()
        }
    }
    return {onStart, onStop}
}
```

and inject it in the Draggable:

```
<Draggable
    onDrag={handleDrag}
    {...useClickObserver(myOnClickCallback)}
>
```

See full source here:
https://gitlab.com/ggpack/banana/-/blob/master/src/components/Emitter.js#L22

Live example (PWA):
https://ggpack.gitlab.io/banana

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation()` doesn't work for me. But `cancel` does.

```
render() {
        return (
            <Draggable
             cancel=".field"
            >
                <div className="pokedex">
                    <div className="screen">
                        {this.state.isSearching ? (<Loader/>) : null}
                        {this.state.hasFound ? this.renderResult() : null}
                        {this.state.hasError ? (<p className="text-center error">{this.state.hasError}</p>) : null}
                    </div>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>
                        <input className="field" type="text" placeholder="Who is this pokemon?" onChange={(e) => this.setPokemon(e.target.value)}/>
                        {this.state.isSearching ? <input className="button text-center" disabled type="submit" value="Find!"/> : <input className="button text-center" type="submit" value="Find!"/>}
                    </form>
                    <div className="button-group">
                        <div className="blue-button"/>
                        <div className="green-button"/>
                        <div className="orange-button"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Draggable>
        )
    }
```